# sed: How to substitute within a match?

Tags: regex, sed, posix, sh

Using [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/), I wrote the expression `/[\.!?] [A-Z]/g` to match sentences using 3 assumptions:

1. Sentences end with punctuation: [.,!?] (I'm not sure how to match double punctuation marks or combinations...)
2. One or more spaces always follow the punctuation mark.
3. The next sentence begins with a CAPITAL letter. (True 99% of the time, except for lowercase nouns such as iDevices)

Using `sed`, I'd like to take these matches, and substitute the space(s) with a `\n` character. I can do an after match $' and a before match $`, but how can I replace within a match?

If there is a better way of splitting texts into one sentence per line, I'm open to alternatives.

No bashisms: for Linux, OS X, and BSD

Input:

> Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut
>   tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper
>   ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi
>   diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi.

Output:

```
Vivamus fermentum semper porta.
Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio.
Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies.
Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this replacement:

```
sed 's/\([.!?][.!?]*\)  *\([A-Z]\)/\1\n\2/g;' file
```

`\(...\)` delimits a capture groups and `\1` is a reference to the captured content.

The OSX version of sed doesn't interpret `\n` as a newline, you must use instead the sequence `\1'$'\n\\2` as replacement string.

A more POSIX way consists to write:

```
sed 's/\([.!?][.!?]*\)  *\([A-Z]\)/\1\
\2/g;' file
```

with an escaped newline as suggested by @cliffordheath.

Note that the dot doesn't need to be escaped inside a character class.

Comment: On OS X: `sed 's/\([.!?][.!?]*\)  *\([A-Z]\)/\1\'$'\n\\2/g` (I had to escape `\n` and also `\2` for some reason), but your answer is the best one so far, because it also takes into account uppercase letters.

Comment: you don't need to take care of letters at all in your case

Answer (score 0):

You need to use capture groups with \( and \) to re-insert the punctuation and initial letter. This example allows a following sentence to start with any alphanumeric (but requires at least one space to avoid messing up decimal numbers):

```
$ sed -e 's/\([.!?]\)  *\([[:alnum:]]\)/\1\
\2/g'
foo.   bat!  baz?  foo,  bar.
foo.
bat!
baz?
foo,  bar.
```

I hope this helps.